# JRE won't install

Tags: java

Months ago I tried upgrading JRE to 8-111 and after several tries I decided to give up as the online installer had the "This program might not have installed correctly" window pop up every time, and the offline one just didn't do anything aside running for a couple of seconds as jre-8u111-windows-i586.exe*32 before closing the process.
I tried again today and the results were the same. Should I just install an older version and stay stuck with it, or is there a fix for this? There currently isn't a version installed, so it shouldn't be some kind of conflict.
Running on W7.

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit Windows 7?

Comment: Running x64 as the properties say, but the x64 installer won't even download. As a last resort I tried with the other as well, but seems like Java doesn't like me. And the online one, jxpiinstall.exe has no x64 or x32 so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Is the problem with downloading or with installation?

Comment: The offline x64 doesn't download. The offline x32 does but after double clicking just dies after a couple of secs. The online one downloads, starts but says the program haven't installed correctly.